# Let $A=[0,1]\times[0,1], f:A\mapsto \mathbb{R} $ bounded in A. Then the set $D_{f,A}$ of discontinuities of $f$ in $A$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, measurable-sets

I think that the statement is true, but I don't know how to start yet. Could anyone help me or give me a hint? I will really appreciate that!

Comment: This is false in one dimension at least. I don't see why it should be true in two dimensions, but I'm having trouble thinking of a counterexample.

Comment: A fríend told me the same but we haven't found the counterexample yet so we think that it might be true

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but why can't you just take a 1-d counterexample and embed it in a stupid way in 2 dimensions (i.e. f is our 1-d counterexample along $[0,1]x\{0\}$ and 0 elsewhere (assuming our counterexample is something which is 0 almost everywhere).

Comment: @user113102 That would work too I think. It would be discontinuous at the same points because approaching from at least one direction doesn't yield $0$.

Comment: A set of continuity is a $G_\delta$ so a set of discontinuity is an $F_\sigma$, not necessarily closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac 1{q_1q_2}&\mbox{ if }x=\frac{p_1}{q_1}\mbox{ and }y=\frac{p_2}{q_2}\mbox{ are both rational}\\
0&\mbox{ if either is irrational}
\end{cases}$$
Then this is discontinuous on $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})\cap ([0,1]\times [0,1])$ and continuous on the complement.

Comment: I might be wrong but... Isn't this set closed? because the elements of that set are isolated points.. aren't they?

Comment: Well, at least its interior is empty

Comment: @Eduardo Certainly not closed. Its closure is the whole space.

Comment: But the whole space is [0,1]$\times$[0,1] wich is closed...

Comment: @Eduardo Yes, the closure of a subset is always closed. But if a set is not equal to its closure then it is not closed.

Comment: Oh! I forgot that fact. You are right, sorry. Thanks a lot!